# SQL INSERT CLAUSE

Tags: sql-server

I have the following INSERT statement:

```
INSERT INTO REVISIONS (PART ,REVNUM ,REV ,REVDATE ,T$PROC ,FATQUANT ,VALIDDATE , SERIALNAME , FROMDATE ,TILLDATE ,REVDES,
                        NEXTSIGN ,CONFIRMED ,ECO,PARTREV )
SELECT PART ,1,REV + row_number() over (order by (select NULL)),0,0,0,0,' ',14770080 ,32610240 ,'tsrif',1,' ' ,32,0
FROM PART  
WHERE LEFT(PARTNAME,4) IN ('1089','1113');
```

I have 620 records that comply with the WHERE clause but only 456 are inserted.
I cannot figure out why.

Comment: How many rows do you get when you run just the select statement?

Comment: Are there any triggers on the `Revisions` table?

Comment: I HAVE 620 ROWS WHEN I RUN JUST SELECT STATMENT.

Comment: THERE ARE NO TRIGGERS

Comment: wanna try inserting those records into a #temp table to validate the data or you can use [EXCEPT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188055.aspx) to validate the result from the table REVISIONS(once inserted) vs the select statement just to check the missing records, based on that analyze the info and get conclusion about filterings and stuff

Comment: maybe because some data has the same Primary Key?

Comment: the rev column is a primary key ,

Comment: Mark thanks . the rev field is a Primary Key. I replaced  "REV + row_number() over (order by (select NULL))" by 1 + row_number() over (order by (select NULL)) it fixed the error   thanks to all;